# How to detect and implement touch events for single tap on home button?

Tags: objective-c, ios10, uitouch, uiresponder

Not sure if it is possible but is there any way to detect a single touch on the home button. To start with, I would simply like to add an NSLog if the user touches down once on the home button (without actually pressing), but I don't know where I would add this functionality. Does Apple allow you to interact with the home button?

I looked at the app delegate methods, but I can't see how any would work in a single tap (touch) context. Would really appreciate your help.

Comment: When you tap on home button, app will goto `background` mode. You can write your logic in AppDelegate's method:- `applicationDidEnterBackground`

Comment: Hi @pkc456 By 'tap' I mean 'touch', not press - so a single touch down on the home button without clicking/pressing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does Apple allow you to interact with the home button?

No, not yet. There are no APIs available to *explicitly* detect home button interactions. 
You can rely on the traditional `app delegate` lifecycle function invocations to perform any logic you wanted to.

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later. 
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
}
```

Comment: Ah. All of those methods look as though they pertain to when the app is about to to be terminate or made inactive, is that correct? In the ordinary running of the app, can I detect a single touch on the home button, at any point while the app is still active?

Comment: @hinterbu No, no home button touches events APIs are available. An application cannot decipher any touch/tap on the device's home button.